# App shortcuts: how to include 'delete' key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I want to switch shortcuts for two actions in Adobe Lightroom:

- Action 1 < set any other shortcut, I'm so sick of calling it by misclick!
- Action 2 < set shortcut used for action 1 (which is cmd+delete)

The app doesn't offer the option. System Preferences>...>App Shortcuts don't allow to use 'delete' key in the shortcut. Answer to a similar question about Services is out-of-date - I can't find the right system file.